# Inventory count of my database keeps starting at 28?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, shopping-cart

I am new to coding and in my code and i am having trouble updating my database. 
 I am using mysql and php to create a shopping cart that updates inventory when an item is purchased. The cart takes the product id of the item and stores it using the GET array. The problem is that after someone purchases an item, the inventory doesn't adjust probably in my database.  the inventory count always starts at 28 every time I purchase an item instead of starting at the proper inventory amount.  The code for the shopping cart is:

```
require 'connect.php';
require 'item.php';
  if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $result = mysqli_query($con, 'select * from products where 
  id='.$_GET['id']);
  $products = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
  $item = new Item();
  $item->id = $products->id;
 $item->name = $products->name;
  $item->price = $products->price;
  $item->quantity = 1;
  $_SESSIONS['id']=$_GET['id'];
  // Check if the products exists in the cart
  $index = -1;
  $cart = unserialize(serialize($_SESSION['cart']));
 for($i=0; $i<count($cart); $i++)
  if($cart[$i]->id==$_GET['id'])
  {
  $index = $i;
  break;
  }
if($index==-1)
 $_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
else{
$cart[$index]->quantity++;
$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
}
```

}

```
// Delete products in cart
if(isset($_GET['index'])){
  $cart = unserialize(serialize($_SESSION['cart']));
  unset($cart[$_GET['index']]);
  $cart = array_values($cart);
  $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
  }  

 if(array_key_exists('submit2', $_POST))
   {  
 $results = mysqli_query($con, "select * from products"); 
 $sql="";//init
 while($products=mysqli_fetch_object($results)){

 for($i=0; $i<count($cart); $i++){    
 $idcart=$cart[$i]->id;
 $quantity= $products->quantity;
 $cartquantity = $cart[$i]-> quantity;
 $sql= "UPDATE products SET quantity='$quantity' - ".$cartquantity." WHERE id='$idcart';";//u need this to append the query
session_destroy(); }//end for
}//end while
if ($con->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {//use multi_query
header("location: thankyou.php");
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
}
 $con->close();
```

I believe the problem is in this code here.  $sql= "UPDATE products SET quantity='$quantity' - ".$cartquantity." WHERE id='$idcart';";.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: please use prepared statement for security purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole logic around updating the cart quantities seems to be unusual.  You have a loop which loops over all of the products and then updates a somehow related database record based on the id from the cart with the quantity from the product.  There is no attempt to match the quantity from the product ID with the ID from the cart.

This code just loops through the cart and reduces the quantity of the matching product for each row, it also prepares the statement before the loop and just executes it once for each row...

```
if(array_key_exists('submit2', $_POST))
{
    $sql = "UPDATE products 
                SET quantity = quantity - ?  
                WHERE id= ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    foreach ( $cart as $item ){
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $item->quantity, $item->id );

        $stmt->execute();
    }//end foreach
    session_destroy();
}//end if
```

Comment: This also shows how useful prepared statements can be, so worth spending a bit of time to learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the quantity values directly  in  update

```
$sql = "UPDATE products SET quantity= quantity - ?  WHERE id= ? ;"
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $cartquantity, $idcart, );

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! the inventory amounts are updating properly, but for some reason, it is now only updating the last item in my cart.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to concatenate your multi query sql on the line with this code:

```
$sql= "UPDATE products SET quantity='$quantity' - ".$cartquantity." WHERE id='$idcart';"
```

Please put concat operator like this:

```
$sql .= "UPDATE products SET quantity='$quantity' - ".$cartquantity." WHERE id='$idcart';"
```

Or like this:

```
$sql= $sql."UPDATE products SET quantity='$quantity' - ".$cartquantity." WHERE id='$idcart';"
```

I noticed you are executing your update SQL after loop which is fine but without concatenation you are only executing the last query in your loop.

Comment: Don't do that. Use parameters in the query and bind values to them. See the other answers.

Comment: That is an inefficient query. Its not advised to run update query multiple times in loop unless you use transaction. No need to down-vote.